# How to set color of PageViewModel Title & body text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my **introScreen.dart**, I want to set a color of **PageViewModel Title & body text** in Flutter.

I am tried this line of code `style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),` but it could be error.

how we can set the color of PageViewModel Title & body text in Flutter?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: IntroductionScreen(
          pages: [
            PageViewModel(
              image: LottieBuilder.asset("assets/animations/1.json"),
              title: "Welcome to $appname",
              body: "I will take you around to see what's so exciting about $appname",
            ),
            PageViewModel(
              image: LottieBuilder.asset("assets/animations/2.json"),
              title: "Privacy Protection",
              body: "Internet access is mind-free, we'll keep you safe",
            ),
            PageViewModel(
              image: LottieBuilder.asset("assets/animations/3.json"),
              title: "Fast and Limitless!",
              body: "We provide you the without limits",
            ),
          ],
          showSkipButton: true,
          onDone: () {
            Preferences.init().then((value) {
              // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
              rootState!.setState(() {
                value.saveFirstOpen();
              });
            });
          },
```

Comment: can you share PageViewModel contains? It is not a widget from flutter, seems a custom created

Comment: PageViewModel package: https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen

Comment: Did you tried with ```pageDecoration``` ? ``` decoration: const PageDecoration(
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
    bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0),
  ),```

Comment: @Maikzen: PageViewModel() Widget is part of the package `introduction_screen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** *Change PageViewModel **Text Colour***:

```
PageViewModel(
  title: "Title of first page",
  body: "Here you can write the description of the page, to explain someting...",
  image: const Center(child: Icon(Icons.android)),
  decoration: const PageDecoration(
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
    bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 20.0),
  ),
)
```

**2.** *Change PageViewModel **Background***:

```
PageViewModel(
  title: "Title of first page",
  body: "Here you can write the description of the page, to explain someting...",
  image: Center(child: Image.asset("res/images/logo.png", height: 175.0)),
  decoration: const PageDecoration(
    pageColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
)
```

You can refer to the [pub.dev documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside `PageViewModel`:

```dart
titleWidget: Text(
            "Welcome to $appname",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: appColorYellow),
          ),

bodyWidget: Text(
            "I will take you around to see what's so exciting about $appname",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: appColorYellow),
          ),
```